# reactjs: react hook form: not checking onchange errors only after first submit

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am using react hook form.

I have a simple textfield with checking number of characters

```
<Controller
  defaultValue=""
  name="accountid"
  control={control}
  rules={{
    maxLength: { value: 10, message: "Cant be more than 10 digits" },
  }}
  render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
    <TextField
      {...field}
      sx={{ width: "14ch" }}
      type="text"
      inputRef={ref}
      label="Account Id"
      margin="dense"
      error={errors.accountid}
      InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
      helperText={errors.accountid?.message}
    />
  )}
/>
```

what i found is when i type for the time 15 characters it does not show error out

but when i submit then it shows the errors

and there after if i clear the text and type more than 15 it immediately shows the error (that "Cant be more than 10 digits")

why react hook onchange is not working in the initial form filling, only works on subsequent form submit

- till first submit no error

[image]

- after first submit

[image]

after that when i retype is works fine, the moment i enter more than 10 characters is shows error

i want this to happen even in the first time